# Laravel Policy не работает

Tags: laravel, policy

В AuthServiceProvider модель и политика зарегистрированы, сам AuthServiceProvider имеется в app.php, registerPolicies точно отрабатывает, методы в котроллере соответствуют методам политик согласно документации laravel, но "магия laravel" не работает и методы политики не вызываются. Если в контроллере прописать  $this->authorizeResource() то все ОК, но этот метод  в документации прописан что его можно использовать и я так понял что он не обязательный.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The model to policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array<class-string, class-string>
 */
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::viaRequest('custom', function (Request $request) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->id = 1010;
        return $user;
    });
}
}
```

PostPolicy

```
class PostPolicy
{
use HandlesAuthorization;

/**
 * Determine whether the user can view any models.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
 */
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    return $user->id === 100;
}
```

PostController

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

public function __construct() {
   // $this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return "Test Data Test";
}
```

api

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);
});
```

auth

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
  ],
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

app

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],
```

Comment: В английском важен контекст, и то что написано о возможности, не говорит о том, что можно вообще забить)
То есть вы **обязаны** использовать или `$this->authorize()` для любого метода контроллера или `$this->authorizeResource()` для ресурсных контроллеров. Ничего не указывать Вы не можете (собственно, логично, что тогда ничего не сработает).